# Positive vs. Negative pulse on an electrode

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, signal-processing

For a particle detector (e.g. ionization chamber, proportional counter,...), what factor determines the polarity of the pulse of the "raw" signals (signals straight from the electrodes before going through an amplifier)?

Comment: Kind of depends on the particle detector, no? Also don't ignore the presence of any preamps in the device.

Comment: I was under the impression that there is a general rule that dictates the signal's polarity. Something like maybe the type of charge that the electrode collects. Regarding the preamps, I am ignoring it since it's usually an "add-on" that exists outside of the detector. For this case, I am only interest in the detector only.

Comment: Well, electron multipliers don't really care whether an energetic electron, ion, or photon hit the input - all the rest is electrons being multiplied.